# How to make image inside <div> is responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have blocks and inside has three boxes.
All are responsive as shown in the image.
[image: ima]
CSS are shown below.

```
.blocks {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 450px; 
}


.box1, .box2, .box3 {

    width: 33.333%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    text-align: center;

}
```

When I insert image, the image is not responsive.
My HTML is shown below.

```
<div class="blocks">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box1" style="background-color:lavender;">
           <?php 
                $args = array( 
            'type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'category__in' => '23',

            );

        $lastBlog = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                if( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):
                    while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); ?>
             <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  
                    the_post_thumbnail(); 
                    the_title( sprintf('<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h3>' );  
             } ?>
            <?php endwhile;
              endif;
              wp_reset_postdata();      
           ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box2" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
           <?php 
                $args = array( 
            'type' => 'post',
            'category__in' => '23',
            'posts_per_page' => 1, 
            'offset' => 1,


            );

        $lastBlog = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                if( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):
                    while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); ?>
             <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                    the_title( sprintf('<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h3>' );  
             } ?>
            <?php endwhile;
              endif;
              wp_reset_postdata();      
           ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box3" style="background-color:lavender;">
           <?php 
                $args = array( 
            'type' => 'post',
            'category__in' => '23',
            'posts_per_page' => 1, 
            'offset' => 2,


            );

        $lastBlog = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                if( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):
                    while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); ?>
             <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                    the_title( sprintf('<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h3>' ); 
             } ?>
            <?php endwhile;
              endif;
              wp_reset_postdata();      
           ?>   
      </div>
    </div>
```

My images are taken from posts.

The problem is when the page size become smaller, the images overlap each other. 
[image: img]

How can I make images inside the `divs` are also responsive?

EDIT:
Putting inside `<img>` tag works.
I did like

```
<img class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%"
           <?php 
                $args = array( 
            'type' => 'post',
            'category__in' => '23',
            'posts_per_page' => 1, 
            'offset' => 1,


            );

        $lastBlog = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                if( $lastBlog->have_posts() ):
                    while( $lastBlog->have_posts() ): $lastBlog->the_post(); ?>
             <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                    the_title( sprintf('<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ),'</a></h4>' ); 
             } ?>
            <?php endwhile;
              endif;
              wp_reset_postdata();      
           ?>
```

But the problem is I can't close the `<img` with `>` at the end. If I put `>` at the end, `>` appears as text on the page.

Comment: You can use bootstrap's rows and img-responsive.

Comment: Your bottom piece of code looks like you're trying to put a `h4` and an `a` _inside_ the `img` tag, is that right? But that's impossible, you can't nest html tags. You can only put html tags inside the _content_ of a html element, but `img` doesn't have content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
.box1 img,
.box2 img,
.box3 img

{

width: 100%;
height:auto; 

}
```

Comment: This is the setting what I am expecting.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using bootstrap, just put a class property of image responsive on the image

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="....">
```

Comment: I put like this <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box2 img-responsive" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">. But still the same.

Comment: Thanks. I can't close <img tag with >. Once I put > then, this > appears as text on the page. I discussed in the EDIT.

Comment: sorry for the omission of the forward slash before the closing tag

Answer (score 1):

you can use class="img-responsive" for make this

Comment: I put like this <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box2 img-responsive" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">. But still the same.

Comment: you have to add this class on img tag not on div

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_img_responsive&stacked=h

Answer (score 1):

if your application use Bootstrap then by all means use

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="....">
```

otherwise try:

```
.box1 img, .box2 img, .box3 img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto; 
}
```

Comment: The first one is fine. But Thanks. I can't close <img tag with >. Once I put > then, this > appears as text on the page. I discussed in the EDIT.